# SQL Query Output is always NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why is the output from my SQL query always NULL? any ideas?

```
set @sql_query = 'select'  + convert(nvarchar(1),@day_segment) + ' = case
                        when isnull(a.D'+convert(nvarchar(3), @day_number ) +'_AIN = ,999) = 999 then 1
                        else 2 end
                        from UKIT_AVAILABILITY_RECORDS a
                        where a.PATTERN_NAME = ''' + @pattern_name + ''''

            execute sp_executesql @sql_query, N'@day_segment int OUTPUT', @day_segment = @day_segment output
```

Comment: Print out `@sqlquery` and at least one syntax error should be obvious.  Of course, you also do not use `@day_segment` in the query.

Comment: share  sql query separately

Answer (score 0):

If any of those variables are NULL your output is going to become NULL, take the follow query for example:

```
SELECT NULL + 'ABC' AS NULLCHECK
```

Returns null, I would print each variable you are dealing with before the execute and make sure they are set properly:

```
PRINT @DAY_SEGMENT
PRINT @DAY_NUMBER
PRINT @PATTERN_NAME
```

Alternatively you could wrap each in an

```
 SELECT ISNULL(@DAY_Segment,'')
```

to verify the exact culprit.

Answer (score 0):

1. `convert(nvarchar(1),@day_segment)`

replace to

```
 'SELECT @day_segment = ' case ..
```

2. If SELECT retruns 0 rows NULL variable